# Change name to exported Excel of a HTML table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, html-table

I'm using this little Javascript function to export a HTML table to an excel archive:

```
$("#btn_export").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(HTML_table));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem is, that the name of the excel archive is always "download"

[image]

Sorry the image is in Spanish. What can I do to change the archive name?

Comment: try using this function to download your file?
https://gist.github.com/1031969